# pyInstaller exe failed because it did not include a module

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

Situation: Building an EXE from a python script that encrypts things.

Problem: The EXE always fails as it cannot find modules that I have imported (`Crypto`).

Question: Is there a flag I need to turn on or include to make sure that pyInstaller includes `Crypto` when building the EXE?

Additional information: The `Crypto` here refers to `pycryptodome`

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your .spec file to include the hiddenimports.  As shown here:

```
hiddenimports=['pycryptodome.apps'],
```

Run pyinstaller with the .spec command afterwards `pyinstaller --name=appname appname.spec`

Then you'll have to add the modules that are in your site-package to the root dist application folder.  Just copy and paste the entire folder.